# Add read permission for all administrators to a copied file

Tags: windows, security, winapi, acl

Problem is simple my application copies some file from one location to another.
File at destination folder should be readable by all administrators of computer without elevating privileges.

I've found an API which should do it:

- [SetNamedSecurityInfoW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfow)
- [SetKernelObjectSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-setkernelobjectsecurity)

But I'm not fluent with Windows API and this security API is quite complex, so I need help ho to use this API.
Main problem I have is how to get `psidGroup`? Other stuff is obvious or I can just provide a `NULL`.

Or is there a better API so I can add this read permission for administrators while file is copied?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. There are plenty of tutorials and examples floating around if you do an online search.

Comment: I did a search it, but apparently I'm asking google a wrong questions, since nothing useful come up. This is how I've found `SetNamedSecurityInfo`.

Comment: Object security is based on a security descriptor that includes control flags, the owner SID, the group SID (not used by Windows access checks), and two optional lists of access control entries (ACEs). The discretionary access-control list (DACL) includes ACEs that grant or deny access to an SID (user or group). The system access-control list (SACL) can include audit ACEs, a mandatory-label ACE that sets the object integrity level and policy (write-up, read-up, execute-up), resource-attribute ACEs, and scoped-policy ACEs.

Comment: By "readable by all administrators of computer without elevating privileges" I assume you mean that it should not require enabling SeBackupPrivilege and opening the file with backup semantics. Granting generic-read access to the local administrators group is easily done. If you instead mean the file should be accessible by UAC-limited administrator logons without requiring elevating to the full administrator token, I don't think that's possible in general.

Comment: @eryksun this is what I've meant. Other administrator with elevated privileges can access this file. Ok so I have to find other solution to this problem.

Comment: Being an administrator is an elevated privilege in itself. On top of that, administrators have super privileges such as SeBackupPrivilege, SeRestorePrivilege, and SeDebugPrivilege, which have to be manually enabled.  To clarify what I meant about the file being accessible to UAC-limited administrator logos, I mean that it would also have to be accessible to standard users. If you want it to be readable only by administrators, then an administrator will need to "run as administrator" (a shell or program) in order to elevate to the full linked administrator token.

Answer (score 0):

`psidGroup` in `SetNamedSecurityInfo` is used to change owner or group of the file. There is [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--) on msdn, get the old Security Info first, then modify(`SetEntriesInAcl`) and submit(`SetNamedSecurityInfo`). If you want to set the permission of the a group, set the [`EXPLICIT_ACCESS.Trustee.TrusteeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-_trustee_type) to `TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP`, then you can set the a permission for a group.